# How to specify label colors for box plots based on pandas df column name/label name in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series of box plots in subplots (see picture) but would like to change the color of the label for each individual plot based on if its DUT1 or DUT2.
[image]

Here is a sample of one of the df used to make the box plots. Each plot is made using a similar df but includes measurements from the various setpoints.

```
      DUT1 A   DUT1 B   DUT2 A   DUT2 B
527  0.92342  0.96342  0.98342  1.00342
528  0.92754  0.88754  0.97754  0.97754
529  0.93655  0.95655  0.99655  0.91655
```

Each number above is the difference between the DUT sensor and the reference sensor for each measurement at the specified set point.

Here is a snapshot how I am creating each subplot of box plots.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols = 4, nrows = 2, sharey = True, figsize = (10,6))
fig.add_subplot(111, frame_on = False)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor = 'none', bottom = False, left = False)
plt.ylabel('Difference from Reference PRT in $^\circ$F', labelpad=20)

boxplot1 = df_setpoint1.boxplot(column = ['DUT1 A','DUT1 B','DUT2 A','DUT2 B'], ax = axes[1,0], rot=45)
boxplot2 = df_setpoint2.boxplot(column = ['DUT1 A','DUT1 B','DUT2 A','DUT2 B'], ax = axes[1,1], rot=45)


axes[1,0].set_title('Set Point -38.5$^\circ$F')
axes[1,1].set_title('Set Point -25$^\circ$F')


fig.suptitle('Temperature Distribution for Temperature Accuracy Testing')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

After some searching, I'm having issues figuring out how to specify the color for each plot label since I'm not creating each box plot individually but rather from specified columns in each dataframe. I come across a lot of custom fill colors for the boxes and adding legends with custom colors but I simply want to control the color of the text labels on the x-axis.

Comment: @Parfait I edited the post to include a sample of the df. thanks.

Comment: Do you mean x-axis label colors? Why not individually color the boxplots? For readability axes should retain same color, leaving plot region to run comparisons. Can't immediately see methods to adjust titles within an axes.

Comment: @Parfait I think I've come around to the same conclusion about readability and a uniform color so I'm satisfied with what I have. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While text label coloring is not immediately convenient, boxplot coloring in the `matplotlib` backend is doable, requiring looping across each patched artist. For each paired `DUT1` and `DUT2` run elementwsie `zip` loop with each artist.

Below runs for one subplot with data provided by OP. To avoid repeating lines integrate into a defined method and run each subplot through it or add a top `for` layer to iterate across all generated subplots in `axes` array.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
...

# BOX PLOT LEGEND
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='The red data')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='The blue data')
fig.legend(handles=[blue_patch, green_patch], labels=['A', 'B'], 
           ncol=2, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.95))
        
# BOX PLOT      
boxplot1 = df_setpoint1.boxplot(column = ['DUT1 A','DUT1 B','DUT2 A','DUT2 B'],
                                ax=axes[1,0], patch_artist=True, rot=45)

# BOX PLOT COLORING
colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green']

for i,(artist, col) in enumerate(zip(axes[1,0].artists, colors)):
    artist.set_edgecolor(col)
    artist.set_facecolor(col) 

    # Each box has 6 associated Line2D objects (to make the whiskers, fliers, etc.)
    # Loop over them here, and use the same colour as above
    for j in range(i*6,i*6+4):
        line = axes[1,0].lines[j]
        line.set_color(col)
        line.set_mfc(col)
        line.set_mec(col)
        line.set_linewidth(0.5)
...

fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.90])
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot Output]